# iCloud Keychain not syincing all iPhone wifi passwords to Mac

Tags: data-synchronization, keychain

I recently upgraded my iPhone 4s to the latest ios 7.1 and my macbook pro to Mavericks and have set up iCloud Keychain sync on both devices.

My problem is that I'm connected to a wifi network on my iPhone and want the password synced to my laptop but when I click on the network on my laptop it asks for a password to this specific Network. On my laptop I'm connected to another wifi network already but it's very slow. Plus, when I was at home this past weekend with fast internet I'm sure it gave my laptop time to synchronise with my iPhone.

But why has all other wifi network passwords been transferred to my laptop but not the one I want to connect to?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Is your laptop connected to the internet at all or not? Because if it isn’t, there’s no way your passwords could sync.

Comment: I'm at a dormitory and we have multiple wifi hotspots, but the one I'm connected to on my Laptop is very slow, so I'd like to connect my laptop to the wifi I'm connected on my iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem as you. I solved it by turning my phone into a hotspot briefly for my laptop, which allowed it to sync new passwords, and then I just clicked on the network, and it didn't prompt me for a password, just connected.

Answer (score 1):

It should sync via internet (icloud), unless maybe the ports needed are blocked on said network. 
Since this is just a single case, save yourseld the headache of troubleshooting and just enter the password again on your mac..

Comment: Problem is, I don't know the password.

Comment: Ask the owner for it. You got it for your iPhone, so you'll probably get it again, no?